# How to animate lists in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I would like to have animated a long list (multi-paged) of items in Angular. So what I already did is to split the list into chunks. Now I'm trying to animate each item in each chuck.

If the first page is rendered, it should wait for a while and then replace the list with the next chunk and start animating again.

```
Chunk #1
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
-- 3 --

Chunk #2
-- 4 --
-- 5 --
-- 6 --

...
```

But for whatever reason, it just renders the first two chunks and it seems that Angular doesn't recognizes that the list has changed.

What is wrong and how can I realize such an animation with Angular animations? I have attached a Stackblitz that shows my current process and the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7aufk

### Update

In the template I've changed

```
  [@listAnimation]="items.length"
```

to

```
  [@listAnimation]="items"
```

Now it plays the animation, but shows two chunks at once and the `:leave` animation is not processed. Please check out the changed stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xfc85a